# Generating a table data by comparing 2 JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

javascript arrays are like below,

```
var course_ids = (1, 2, 3, 4);
var selected = (1, 3);

for (var x = 0; x < course_ids.length; x++) {
  if (selected.find(checkCourse)) {
    table_data += "<td>true</td>";
  } else {
    table_data += "<td>false</td>";
  }
}

$('#exam_tbl tr:last').append(table_data);

function checkCourse(course_id) {
  return course_id;
}
```

html table contain all `course_ids` as `th` in a table row. Then i want to load `selected` into next row. but if selected course is there i want to show true in `td` else want to show false.
 sample is like below.

```
 ---------------------------------
|   1   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   //th
----------------------------------
|true   |false  |true   |false  | //td
-----------------------------------
```

please help me to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Comment: Probably a typo. `sem_course_ids` is undefined. Should be `course_ids` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `join()` to create html string and `includes()` to check if element is included in another array.

```js
var course_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var selected = [1, 3];

$('<tr>').append(course_ids
  .map(id => `<th>${id}</th>`)
  .join(''))
  .appendTo($('thead'))
  
$('<tr>').append(course_ids
  .map(e => `<td>${selected.includes(e)}</td>`)
  .join(''))
  .appendTo($('tbody'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="exam_tb">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Or you could use `reduce()` method and return one object with thead and tbody strings.

```js
var course_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var selected = [1, 3];

var html = course_ids
  .reduce(function(r, e) {
    r.thead += `<th>${e}</th>`;
    r.tbody += `<td>${selected.includes(e)}</td>`;
    return r;
  }, {thead: '', tbody: ''});
  
$('<tr>').append(html.thead).appendTo($('thead'))
$('<tr>').append(html.tbody).appendTo($('tbody'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="exam_tb">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: how can I to add a check box if true and a empty `td` if false here?

Comment: Please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47921510/create-a-table-comparing-3-javascript-arrays

Answer (score 1):

`course_ids` variable must holds an array.

```
course_ids = [1,2,3,4];
```

As you wrote the `course_ids` has value `4`.

This is called `comma separated operator.`

> The comma operator evaluates each of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the last operand.

```js
console.log((1,2,3,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var course_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var selected = [1, 3, 4];
    var table_data = "";

    for (var x = 0; x < course_ids.length; x++) {
      if (selected.indexOf(course_ids[x]) != -1) {
        table_data += "<td>true</td>";
      } else {
        table_data += "<td>false</td>";
      }
    }

    console.log(table_data);

$('#exam_tbl tr:last').append(table_data);
```